# Python executing functions in Classes

Tags: python, file, class

I'm struggling a little understanding how to use classes effectively. I have written a program which I hope to count the number of occurrences of a phrase or word in a .txt file.

I'm not quite sure how to call the function properly, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
class WordCounter:
    def The_Count(self):  
        print "Counting words..."       
        txt_doc = open("file")

        for line in txt_doc:
            if "word" in txt_doc:
                word_freq = word_freq + 1
                return word_freq

        print "Frequency of word: %s" % word_freq
```

WordCounter.The_Count

Comment: This is not an effective use of classes, even with the correct code.

Comment: def The_Count(self): Don't forget to include a class reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several problems here, the code you posted isn't correct python. class methods should take a reference to self as an argument:

```
def The_Count(self):
```

you need to initialize word_freq for the case where there are no words to count:

```
word_freq = 0
```

as others have mentioned, you can call your function this way:

```
counter = WordCounter()
print(counter.The_Count())
```

It's not really idiomatic python to wrap these kinds of stateless functions in classes, as you might do in Java or something. I would separate this function into a module, and let the calling class handle the file I/O, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using classes is a little different than what you have tried to do here.  Think of it more in terms of preserving variables and state of objects in code. To accomplish your task, something more like the following would work:

```
class CountObject(object):
    """Instance of CountObject for measuring file lengths"""
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    def getcount(self, word):
        count = 0
        infile = open(self.filename,'r')
        for line in infile.readlines():
            x = line.count(word)
            count = count + x
        return count

mycounter = CountObject('C:\list.txt')
print 'The occcurence of awesome is %s' %(str(mycounter.getcount('in')))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, just to agree on the names, a function inside a class is called a *method* of that class.

In your example, your method performs the action of counting occurrences of words, so to make it clearer, you could simply call your method `count`. Note also that in Python, it is a [convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) to have method names start with a lower case.

Also, it is good practice to use so called [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle) which are simply classes that inherits from `object`.

Finally, in Python, a method needs to have at least one parameter, which is [by convention](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) called `self` and which should be an instance of the class.

So if we apply these changes, we get something like:

```
class WordCounter(object):

    def count(self):  
        print "Counting words..."
    
        # Rest of your code
        # ...
```

Now that your class has a method, you first need to create an instance of your class before you can call that method on it. So, to create an instance of a class `Foo` in Python, you simply need to call `Foo()`. Once you have your instance, you can then call your method. Using your example

```
# Create an instance of your class and save it in a variable
my_word_counter = WordCounter()
# Call your method on the instance you have just created
my_word_counter.count()
```

Note that you don't need to pass in an argument for self because [the Python interpreter will replace](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) `self` with the value of `word_counter` for you, i.e. it calls `WordCounter.count(my_word_counter)`.

#### A note on OO

Has noted by others, your example is not a great use of classes in Python. OO classes aim at putting together behaviours (instance methods) along with the data they interact with (instance attributes). You example being a simple one, there is no real internal data associated with your class. A good warning could be the fact that you never use `self` inside your method.

For behaviour that is not tied to some particular data, Python gives you the flexibility to write module-level functions - Java, in opposition, forces you to put absolutely everything inside classes.

As suggested by others too, to make your example more OO, you could pass the filename as a param to `__init__` and save it as `self.filename`. Probably even better would be to have your `WordCounter` expect a file-like object, so that it is not responsible for opening/closing the file itself. Something like:

```
class WordCounter(object):

    def __init__(self, txt_doc):
        self.word_file = txt_doc

    def count(self):
        print "Counting words..."       

        for line in self.txt_doc:
            # Rest of your code
            # ...
            
with open(filename) as f:
    word_counter = WordCounter(f)
    word_counter.count()
```

Finally, if you want more details on classes in Python, a good source of information is always the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

To call a method in a class, first you have to create an instance of that class:

```
c = WordCounter()
```

Then you call the method on that instance:

```
c.TheCount()
```

However, in this case you don't really need classes; this can just be a top-level function. Classes are most useful when you want each object to have its own internal state.

Comment: Note that `c.TheCount` still will raise an exception here (wrong number of arguments, no `self` in `def TheCount():`).  to make it work, decorate TheCount with @staticmethod

Comment: What does the self actually do in the arguments?

Comment: @Behzad: In your case, nothing. Hence my comment up top.

Comment: @Behzad -- self is a conventional name which means "This class object".  In the example above, the object `c` would be passed in as `self`.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

For such a small program, using classes may not be necessary. You could simply define the function and then call it.

However, if you wanted to implement a class design you could use (after class definition):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

wc = WordCounter() #create instance
wc.TheCount() #call method
```

The use of a class design would use better design principles while increasing the readability/flexibility of your code if you wanted to further expand the capabilities of the class later.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'd have to change the code to this:

```
class WordCounter:
    def CountWords(self):
        # For functions inside classes, the first parameter must always be `self`
        # I'm sure there are exceptions to that rule, but none you should worry about
        # right now.
        print "Counting words..."          
        txt_doc = open("file")   
        word_freq = 0

        for line in txt_doc:   
            if "word" in line:   # I'm assuming you mean to use 'line' instead of 'txt_doc'
                word_freq += 1   
                # count all the words first before returning it

        txt_doc.close()          # Always close files after you open them.  
                                 # (also, consider learning about the 'with' keyword)

        # Either print the frequency
        print "Frequency of word: %s" % word_freq 
        # ...or return it.
        return word_freq
```

...then to call it, you would do....

```
>>> foo = WordCounter()  # create an instance of the class
>>> foo.CountWords()     # run the function
```

As other posters have noted, this is *not* the most effective uses of classes.  It would be better if you made this into a top-level function, and changed it to this:

```
def CountWords(filename, word):
    with open(filename) as txt_doc:
        word_freq = 0
        for line in txt_doc:
            if word in line:
                word_freq += 1
    return word_freq
```

...and called it like this:

```
>>> output = CountWords("file.txt", "cat")
>>> print "Frequency of word: %s" % output
39
```

---

It would make a bit more sense to use a class if you had something like the below, where you have a bunch of variables and functions all related to one conceptual 'object':

class FileStatistics:
    def **init**(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

```
def CountWords(self, word):
    pass   # Add code here...

def CountNumberOfLetters(self):
    pass

def AverageLineLength(self):
    pass

# ...etc.
```